# How to stack up TD elements of just one ROW of a table in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Ideally I would use divs, but it is not an option.

I need too stack up or pile up TD inside one row of a table, while leaving the rest as it is.

With display: block; it kind of works, except then all the TD stack up are only the width of one column. (see code)

Is there a way to, in css, stack up TD and make them 100% of the row?

Many thanks in advance!

```css
.red {
  
  border: solid red 0.25em ;
  display: block;
}

.blue {
  
  border: solid blue 0.25em ;
  display: block;
  
}


td {
    border: solid grey 0.25em ;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>top row</td>
    <td>top row</td>
    <td>top row</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="blue" > needs to go on top of the other td</td>
    <td class="red" >
    </td>
    <td class="red">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what yuo need. But, if you need a tr on top of a table, you can use [thead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) like below

```html
<table>
    <caption>Council budget (in £) 2018</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Donuts</th>
            <td>3,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Stationery</th>
            <td>18,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Items</th>
            <th scope="col">Expenditure</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to specify, I need to figure this out in CSS

Comment: Just with CSS I dont know how to this. I think you can modify the DOM with javascript and inject the TD on the top.

I hope you find some aswear.